# Why might I be getting "Permission denied" for a directory that seems to have correct permissions?

Tags: linux, bash, permissions

I'm a member of the group that owns the directory `dir`, but I can't seem to access it. I'm not sure why I could possibly not have permission. See below:

```
$ groups
various including dir

$ cd dir
-bash: cd: dir: Permission denied

$ ls -ld dir/
drwxrwx---. 4 whoever dir 55 Apr 10 15:12 dir/

$ getfacl dir
# file: dir
# owner: whoever
# group: dir
user::rwx
group::rwx
other::---
```

Comment: Could you check if directory "dir" is not mount point? If it is - then most likely you have  problem with mounted FS.

Comment: Is your disk full?

Comment: Why does the folder have no owner?  My first thought is this behavior is intended.

Comment: @Broomerr Please post that as an answer. Thanks!

Comment: @Ramhound It does have an owner. I changed the name to make that more clear. However, the group ownership was the real issue with which I was concerned. Thanks for your feedback!

Answer (score -2):

have a look at the ACL for the "other" group  try to set

```
getfacl -m other::--x dir
```

try with the -r atribute too !  you can find some doc here : https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Access_Control_Lists

Edit try this : `getfacl -R -m other::r-x dir`

[Linux Group Folder Access](https://superuser.com/questions/206367/linux-group-folder-access?rq=1)

i had a similar problem, now ACL is OK for me :)